# Why does one of my static file is not found when deploying a Django app with Docker?

Tags: django, docker, whitenoise

I am trying to do a django project and push it to Heroku. For now, I just try to make my container work locally. For my static files, I use Whitenoise. The problem I encounter is that my app work and all my statics work except one, script.js (the only file I have in the folder js). I have this error message on the docker console : `Not Found: /static/js/script.js`

This is my Dockerfile :

```
# pull official base image
FROM python:3.8-alpine

# set work directory
WORKDIR /pur_beurre

# set environment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
ENV DEBUG 0

# install psycopg2
RUN apk update \
    && apk add --virtual build-essential gcc python3-dev musl-dev \
    && apk add postgresql-dev \
    && pip install psycopg2

# install dependencies
COPY ./requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# copy project
COPY . .

# collect static files
RUN python manage.py collectstatic --noinput

# add and run as non-root user
RUN adduser -D myuser
USER myuser

# run gunicorn
CMD gunicorn pur_beurre.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:$PORT
```

I have `STATIC_URL = 'staticfiles'` and `STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'staticfiles'` and I added the line `'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',` just after `'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',`.

My js folder is at the same level as my css folder in `/my_app/static/` and he is in `/my_project/staticfiles/my_app/` like the css.

I found a way to see the docker static files deployed. sing the command `docker exec django-heroku ls /my_project/staticfiles/my_app/js`, I can see that script.js is in the folder.

Comment: Can u add the part from settings.py, how the `STATICFILES_DIRS` code looks like?

Comment: @FaisalNazik I dont have the STATICFILES_DIRS set up

Comment: @FaisalNazik I can run collectstatic command without, as I said there is only one file that dont work. Also, I dont see why I would need it, If you follow the django doc : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/ , you only need it set when you have extra folder you would like to collect.